# Why is my screen only showing the wallpaper (Dual boot with Chrome OS)?

Tags: unity

I followed the instructions on the official Ubuntu page for dual booting chrome OS (on a chromebook) and Ubuntu, but going onto Ubuntu, all I see is the wallpaper. Isn’t there supposed to be a top bar, activity overview, app drawer, etc? A textbox pops up whenever I type something, but it doesn’t do anything, as far as I know.

I think I installed 16.04..? I’ve tried the standard commands for finding the version I’m running, but nothing happens when I type them in. I have an ASUS Chromebook Flip C302.

Tutorial I followed:
https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook

Comment: can you post a link to the tutorial you used? did you use crouton

Comment: currently the best way to put ubuntu on your chromebook is with galliumOS https://wiki.galliumos.org/Welcome_to_the_GalliumOS_Wiki

Comment: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte I used crouton. Does GalliumOS use something different?

Comment: GalliumOS is a full on install... it is said to be less buggy than crouton but doesn't offfer OS switching like crouton does... I use galliumOS on my chromebook